# XSLT to Transform XML into Hierarchial Format

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml with values of partyId and parentPartyId in a simple form. I want to convert it into the form of hierarchical tree format.

I have created the schema as per desired output. I am trying Axis Names expressions in http://www.keller.com/xslt/8/. I am not getting, how to convert source into desired format?

Source and required Target are as follows.

**SOURCE:**

```
<OutputCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.test.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/PartyHierarchy">
            <Output>
               <level>1</level>
               <Parent_Party xsi:nil="true"/>
               <Party>Party-1</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>2</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-1</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>2</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-2</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>3</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1-2</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-2-1</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>3</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1-2</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-2-2</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>3</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1-2</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-2-3</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>2</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-3</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>3</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1-3</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-3-1</Party>
            </Output>
            <Output>
               <level>3</level>
               <Parent_Party>Party-1-3</Parent_Party>
               <Party>Party-1-3-2</Party>
            </Output>
         </OutputCollection>
```

**TARGET:**

```
<OutputCollection xmlns="http://xmlns.test.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/PartyHierarchy">
            <Output>
               <level>1</level>
               <Parent_Party xsi:nil="true"/>
               <Party>Party-1</Party>
               <Children>
                    <level>2</level>
                    <Parent_Party>Party-1</Parent_Party>
                    <Party>Party-1-1</Party>
               </Children>
               <Children>
                    <level>2</level>
                    <Parent_Party>Party-1</Parent_Party>
                    <Party>Party-1-2</Party>
                    <Children>
                        <level>3</level>
                        <Parent_Party>Party-1-2</Parent_Party>
                        <Party>Party-1-2-1</Party>
                    </Children>
                    <Children>
                        <level>3</level>
                        <Parent_Party>Party-1-2</Parent_Party>
                        <Party>Party-1-2-2</Party>
                    </Children>
                    <Children>
                        <level>3</level>
                        <Parent_Party>Party-1-2</Parent_Party>
                        <Party>Party-1-2-3</Party>                  
                    </Children>
               </Children>
               <Children>
                    <level>2</level>
                    <Parent_Party>Party-1</Parent_Party>
                    <Party>Party-1-3</Party>
                    <Children>
                        <level>3</level>
                        <Parent_Party>Party-1-3</Parent_Party>
                        <Party>Party-1-3-1</Party>                  
                    </Children>
                    <Children>
                        <level>3</level>
                        <Parent_Party>Party-1-3</Parent_Party>
                        <Party>Party-1-3-2</Party>          
                    </Children>                 
               </Children>
            </Output>
         </OutputCollection>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XSLT, if you need to follow cross-references then you need to define a key `<xsl:key name="children" match="ph:Output" use="ph:Parent_Party"/>` and use it `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', ph:Party)"/>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ph="http://xmlns.test.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/PartyHierarchy"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.test.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/PartyHierarchy"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ph xsi"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="ph:Output" use="ph:Parent_Party"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', '')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ph:Output[ph:Parent_Party/@xsi:nil = 'true']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', ph:Party)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ph:Output">
  <children>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', ph:Party)"/>
  </children>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that your posted input sample uses the prefix `xsi` but does not declare it so I had to assume a namespace for that prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martin!  I spent a lot of hours on following, preceding etc. but this solution works and is very concise.

I am new to advanced XSLT. Can you please suggest any link for concepts or similar problems for practice?

Comment: There is an FAQ compilation http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html. And you should be able to find in-depth explanation of concepts in the various books dedicated to XSLT and XPath that publishers offer. There are also resources online at http://www.cranesoftwrights.com/training/index.htm and the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info page also has links to online courses.

Comment: Thanks Martin!
If possible, can you please show, how we can achieve the same output using Axis names (viz. following-sibling::, preceding:: etc.) too.